# Python | Reformatting each line in a text file consistently

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, text, slice

I have made my own **corpus** of misspelled words.

`misspellings_corpus.txt`:

```
English, enlist->Enlish
Hallowe'en, Halloween->Hallowean
```

---

I'm having an issue with my format. Thankfully, it is at least consistent.

Current format:

```
correct, wrong1, wrong2->wrong3
```

Desired format:

```
wrong1,wrong2,wrong3->correct
```

- The order of `wrong<N>` isn't of concern,
- There might be any number of `wrong<N>` words per line (separated by a comma: `,`),
- There's only 1 `correct` word per line (which should be to the right of `->`).

---

Failed Attempt:

```py
with open('misspellings_corpus.txt') as oldfile, open('new.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
      correct = line.split(', ')[0].strip()
      print(correct)
      W = line.split(', ')[1].strip()
      print(W)
      wrong_1 = W.split('->')[0] # however, there might be loads of wrong words
      wrong_2 = W.split('->')[1]
      newfile.write(wrong_1 + ', ' + wrong_2 + '->' + correct)
```

Output `new.txt` (isn't working):

```
enlist, Enlish->EnglishHalloween, Hallowean->Hallowe'en
```

---

**Solution:** (Inspired by @alexis)

```py
with open('misspellings_corpus.txt') as oldfile, open('new.txt', 'w') as newfile:
  for line in oldfile:
    #line = 'correct, wrong1, wrong2->wrong3'
    line = line.strip()
    terms = re.split(r", *|->", line)
    newfile.write(",".join(terms[1:]) + "->" + terms[0] + '\n')
```

Output `new.txt`:

```
enlist,Enlish->English
Halloween,Hallowean->Hallowe'en
```

Comment: ```newfile.write(wrong_1 + ', ' + wrong_2 + '->' + correct+"\n")```?

Comment: how could you tell if "enlist" is a misspelling and not a separate word?

Comment: @Sujay So part of my problem is that I've any number of "wrong" words on one line. So I cannot deterministically speaking have a finite number of variable objects in a `write()` line. :(

Comment: @AzatIbrakov This is just an example of a much bigger file. Even the given example will suffice for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume all the commas are word separators. I'll break each line on commas *and* arrows, for convenience:

```
import re

line = 'correct, wrong1, wrong2->wrong3'
terms = re.split(r", *|->", line)
new_line = ", ".join(terms[1:]) + "->" + terms[0]
print(new_line)
```

You can put that back in a file-reading loop, right?

Comment: I've made some tweaks to this. I will append to bottom of my post.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Though I'm not sure why you say you made "tweaks", you used the solution in your file reading-writing loop exactly as it was meant to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest building up a list, rather than assuming the number of elements. When you split on the comma, the first element is the correct word, elements [1:-1] are misspellings, and [-1] is going to be the one you have to split on the arrow.

I think you're also finding that write needs a newline character as in "\n" as suggested in the comments.